# Can I test Swift applications on my iPhone with Xcode 6.4 and no developer license?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm seeing mixed answers about this from several blogs. I've heard this feature is only available when Xcode 7 comes out in the fall, but similarly some people say you can test on your own device right now. If possible, any links to good tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where did you hear that?

Comment: its possible through "free provisioning profile" and applicable in Xcode 7 for iOS and WatchOS, this feature is available for Mac OSX in all current xcode

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this feature will be available for Xcode 7 and is not currently an option.

> **Free Provisioning**
>
> - **Develop on your own device**. Part of being successful
>     at debugging and testing is being able to run your app on a physical
>     device. You’ve always been able to build and run on Simulator in the
>     past, but running on a device required a complex set of steps to allow
>     you to install and run your app. With Xcode 7, all you need is an
>     Apple ID and you can develop and test on any device.
>
> See [Launching Your App on Devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27) in *App Distribution Guide* for detailed 
>   information about installing and running on devices.

From [What's New in Xcode - New Features in Xcode 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html)